# Javascript lastIndexOf not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove fakepath from a URL using lastindexof function in pure javascript
But no output is being shown the following is my JS code :-

```
function myFunction()
{
var str="C:\fakepath\somefile.txt";
var m=str.lastIndexOf("\");
var n=str.substring(m+1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
}
```

The following is my HTML code:-

```
<p id="demo">
    Click the button to locate where in the string a specified value occurs.
</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

You can find the working example at my jsfiddle at -> http://jsfiddle.net/xKPaK/4/

Comment: Um, the fact that "u" never occurs in "C:\fakepath\somefile.txt" may have something to do with it...

Comment: @Otome I have edited my fiddle but it is still not working...see the edited link

Comment: You should put the exact code here not something different. Your problem is easily found by the syntax highlighting in jsFiddle. "\" has to be escaped, but not sure if that's the only issue...

Comment: @elclanrs , see my updated link and question...sorry for the mistake..but even after updating the code, it does not work

Comment: The second problem is that you have to select `No wrap - in <head>` in your fiddle.

Comment: When you say that you have escaped the "\", does that mean that you have escaped it both in the `str` source variable and in the `var m=str.lastIndexOf("\");` line?

Comment: @elclanrs look at the updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/xKPaK/7/ . It is working for "." but not for "\"

Comment: I think you're missing the point here. "\" **has** to be escaped in both your string and the `lastIndexOf`, because "\" by itself is used to escape other characters. The fakepath will come escaped already, you're simulating it wrong. I'd just do this though: `'C:\\fakepath\\somefile.txt'.split('\\').pop()`

Comment: @elclanrs , the problem is that I have the string as 'C:\fakepath\somefile.txt' and not 'C:\\fakepath\\somefile.txt'

Comment: Then your real string is actually: `C:akepathsomefile.txt`

Comment: @elclanrs , I got you, so how to convert the original string with on backslash to one with 2 slashes?

Comment: You can't, the string doesn't contain a "\" character so you can't do a replacement. The fakepath from the file input will come already escaped. I don't understand why you create your own string other than for testing, and for that you have to escape backslashes. Put it this way, a literal "\" is always "\\", and you have to write it that way if you want to print that character.

Comment: @elclanrs , just check this fiddle using Google Chrome -> http://jsfiddle.net/ak62C/ . Just select a file and see the output. This is the reason why I want to do this.

Comment: I just tried the code I suggested above and it works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/ak62C/1/. You're printing out the path which is already escaped.

Comment: @BenLind you have to realise that when JavaScript prints the content back, it's already been escaped and is rendered properly. So the only reason you should be escaping backslashes in your code is when you (and no other user interaction) have hard-coded a string yourself.

Comment: @elclanrs , thanks for the answer, I would have chosen it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @BenLind zzzzBov's answer is a perfectly acceptable one, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `\` characters must be escaped
   backslashes are used to create special characters in strings. For example, `'\n'` creates a string with a value of the newline character, while `'\\n'` creates a string with a value of `\n`.
2. `myFunction` must be in global scope to be called in an HTML attribute callback.
   This is a quirk of jsfiddle. The contents of the JavaScript pane are actually executed within a function, which creates new scope for variables and functions. Simply adding the function to the global object will fix the issue.

```
function myFunction() {
    var str,
        m,
        n;
    str = "C:\\fakepath\\somefile.txt";
    m = str.lastIndexOf("\\");
    n = str.substring(m + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
window.myFunction = myFunction;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8R7hB/)

Comment: the problem is that I have the string as 'C:\fakepath\somefile.txt' and not 'C:\\fakepath\\somefile.txt'

Comment: @BenLind, no, you really don't. You have a string *value* that is `C:\fakepath\somefile.txt`, but to represent it as a string *literal* you must escape the ``\`` characters. If you call `alert("C:\\fakepath\\somefile.txt")` it might make more sense.

Comment: @zzzzBov out of interest, if he's reading this string from a text file or the url bar via JavaScript, will JavaScript account for unescaped characters when assigning them to variables? I've done a lot of JavaScripting, but for some reason this never cropped up. God knows how.

Comment: @zzzzBov , this fiddle is for demonstration only, but I have the original string as C:\fakepath\somefile.txt and not as C:\\fakepath\\somefile.txt . So I have to first convert it into C:\\fakepath\\somefile.txt to make this work. So how to add an extra "\" in between the string

Comment: @BenLind as with my question to zzzzBov, the chances are that if you're bringing that string (C:\fakepath\somefile.txt) in from an external source, JavaScript has already escaped it. It could be that you're just hard coding this example because you're debugging. In which case, you need to be wary of adding `\\` to future versions of your code-base. Can you corroborate this zzzzBov?

Comment: @shennan, check this fiddle using Google Chrome -> http://jsfiddle.net/ak62C/ . Just select a file and then see the output. This is the reason why I am doing this JS.

Comment: @shennan is correct. If you're making an AJAX request, or reading a string from a DOM node, the value will be as it was read. Escaping ``\`` characters is necessary for string literals, and you should never be building raw JavaScript with server-side code.

Comment: As a hilarious side-note, I had to escape my \ character when using it in a code snippet (`\\`)